# How to safely check if user is admin and render needed components

Tags: json, reactjs, mongodb

Need your opinion/advice. Now i am developing admin panel on my project. Admin panel is available by url /admin. There will be an authorization form. After entering the data, a request is sent to the server, and there would be validation whether this user is an admin. If user is admin in json will be the appropriate field about it.

After that, client side get state IS_ADMIN and needed components will render. My question is how to safely check if user is admin? Because everyone can set the flag IS_ADMIN with react-devtools.

Comment: "everyone can set the flag IS_ADMIN" - true. Just make sure that the tools, even if enabled by a malicious user, can do nothing (that is, check authorization on the server, don't trust the client).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for reply.